# ignoring a file in svn?

Tags: linux, svn

Im using command and just tried the following:

```
svn propset svn:ignore "conf.php"
```

However this opens up vim and if I exit the file `svn-prop.tmp` file is created.

I don't want to delete it as I need it, but I would love it if svn could just not list it when i `svn st`

What when wrong (`conf.php` is still listed when I `svn st`) and how do I correct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `conf.php` has already been committed, then there are no ignore patterns you can throw at Subversion to get it to ignore the file.

What you probably want to do is:

- `svn mv conf.php conf.php.template`.  This will move `conf.php` to `conf.php.template`.
- `svn commit`.
- `cp conf.php.template conf.php`.

Assuming that you have already set the `svn:ignore` property, then this should do it.  At this point, you will have a versioned `conf.php.template` file that you can modify when you want the configuration stored in the repository to change, and you have an unversioned `conf.php` that you can tweak locally without Subversion informing you that it needs to be committed.

If you check out the repository elsewhere, just make sure that you `cp conf.php.template conf.php` to set up the initial configuration; then you can tweak `conf.php` as needed.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the ignore property on the directory containing the file you want to ignore:

```
svn propedit svn:ignore .
```

then enter the filename(s) to ignore when your editor comes up